# Borland c++ exception

Tags: c++, exception

i am using the Borland c++ 3.1 compiler. I want to work with exceptions, i've written the following code:

```
void main (void) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c;
    try {
        throw 1;
    }
    catch(int a) {
        b = a;
    }
}
```

The compiler returns a syntax error. what's wrong?

Comment: Can I ask what the syntax error says?

Comment: Particularly at what line number?

Comment: Are you sure that is the full error message and that it does not give more information like line numbers and more precise error messages? Don't worry, you can paste exactly what it says. You will not scare us off.

Comment: are you sure you are using 'Borland C++ 3.1'? Wikipedia says that's from 1992 ....if that is true, it is might not support exceptions at all.

Comment: yes i am sure i am using that compiler, because i don't know  some other DOS compilers,
but if it not support exceptions why the try word lighted as keyword? now my main function return 'int'

Comment: Is there a reason you're using that compiler?

Comment: Borland C++ recognized some C++ keywords before they actually implemented it. AFAIR Borland C++ 2.0 listed try, throw, catch and template as keywords in manuals and the compiler didn't support them for sure.

Comment: @Xavar: You need to use a newer compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Most compilers will issue an error stating that your main function must return an int.
The main function must return int in a C++ program. It's unsafe to return void from a main function and many modern compilers won't compile. Aside from that everything looks compilable

Comment: `void` functions don't return a value.

Comment: He has declared main to be void and the compiler would only warn about that at best I think.

Comment: The main function must return int. It's unsafe to return void from a main function and many modern compilers won't compile

Comment: @Robert and Raul -- Comeau: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/  Codepad: http://codepad.org/KGRIwVDm  Declaring main as returning anything other than an int is an error, even if some compilers don't issue it.

Comment: +1 this is true, never use void main() even if your compiler lets you get away with it.

Comment: I agree that it is an error and I would not write my main that way, but is it the error that the poster is getting? I don't think it is.

Comment: Borland C++ 3.1 is ancient, around 1992 according to Wikipedia. I'm amazed that it even has exceptions. It certainly doesn't qualify as "modern".

Comment: Ironically though, you don't actually have to explicitly return a value from main, even though you do have to declare it as type int.

Comment: PigBen - I believe the compiler adds a 'return 0;' automatically.

Comment: Robert Massaioli - I just tested on gcc g++ and it gave me an error because of the return type of main. Though I agree that an old compiler would most likely compile it anyway